# Table name won't change even after set in Laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

OrderProducts Eloquent:

```
class OrderProduct extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'order_products';
}
```

I create a model for my table name called `order_products`.
My Eloquent name is `OrderProduct`. Then I change the table name in Eloquent to protected $table = "order_products"`.

Still, I'm getting order_product table doesn't exist issue?
Why?

Comment: Your error says order_product doesn't exists but you table is order_product**s** maybe that's your error?

Comment: class OrderProduct extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'order_products';
}

Comment: @LucasSaladini yes. But my table name is order_products. When I try to get data from Eloquent it says order_product doesn't exist. The actual table name is order_products

Comment: Changing the Model would not automatically change the table name within your DB

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Model would not automatically change the table name within your DB

You can specify a custom table name by defining a table property on your model:

```
class OrderProduct extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'order_products';
}
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#table-names

Comment: I did this, Still I'm getting this error

Comment: can you run: `composer dump-autoload -o`, and then try again?

Comment: tried. No change. Still same

Comment: Is there a reason to not rename the DB table name to what Laravel expects?

Comment: Thanks Dude. I found the issue

Comment: what is the issue

Comment: @InfasMohammed if my answer helped solve the issue, you can upvote or mark as Solution.